# How to Hadoop Path to Java File

Tags: java, hadoop

I am working on code which processes File objects. I would like to store the actual files in HDFS, but to retrieve them as File objects.
I found the method pathToFile (Hadoop LocalFileSystem), which supposedly does exactly what I want, but it doesn't seem to work.
There is another question with almost the same topic ([How to convert a Hadoop Path object into a Java File object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444313/how-to-convert-a-hadoop-path-object-into-a-java-file-object)) but it isn't solved.

Is there anyone who actually used the method and converted a Hadoop Path to a Java File?

fyi: I searched all over the Internet and I couldn't find not even a chunk of code where the pathToFile is used and works efficiently.

In my code:

```
String uri = args[0]; //give the hdsf path as argument
Configuration conf = new Configuration(); //create a Configuration obj
Path pathOfFile = new Path(uri); //create a Hadoop Path obj
LocalFileSystem myFS = FileSystem.getLocal(conf); //LocalFileSystem creation
File theFile = myFS.pathToFile(pathOfFile); // using pathToFile
```

Comment: is theFile not null? if yes what is theFile.getAbsolutePath() compared to your configs?

Comment: The theFile is what I want to create, but myFS.pathToFile doesn't seem to work!
I get the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: ..."
The args[0] I am giving is "hdfs://localhost:54310/user/giorgos/test.txt", and I know for sure it is stored in HDFS and it works as an HDFS path.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this piece of code could help replace /etc/hadoop/conf with your local config

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.addResource("/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml");
configuration.addResource("/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml");
configuration.addResource("/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml");
FileSystem hdfsFileSystem = FileSystem.get(configuration);
Path pathOfFile = new Path("/user/giorgos/test.txt"));
```