# Atomic move of files with filter in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

So far I have used `FileUtil.copy` to move (i.e. rename) files from one directory to another in on the same Hadoop system. I delete the original file once copied. There's a few constraints that have influenced this decision:

- It has to be done inside the application, so no `hdfs dfs` commands or other shell utilities.
- I need a filter on the list of files (some have to be excluded), so I can only use the `listStatus` method (at least to my knowledge).
- If the target directory exists or contains files, these should just remain there, so no overwriting of existing files.

The problem is `FileUtil.copy` is not atomic (obviously), so for a large number of files this makes the whole operation slow.

Hadoop-compatible file systems need to [guarantee atomicity](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/filesystem/introduction.html#Atomicity) of renaming, which I assume includes moving them to another directory (on the same file system). My problem is that there are two other options I have found but they don't work in my case:

- `FileSystem.rename` assumes that either the target directory does not exist (non-overwrite mode) or that it's empty (overwrite mode), at least according to the source code documentation, which is not in the Javadoc though.
- `FileUtils.replaceFile` (which I'm not sure is even atomic) requires instances of `java.io.File`, which as far as I know cannot be obtained from `FileStatus` instances without first copying the file to a local FS, which pretty much ruins atomicity anyway because I first have to copy the files, rename, and then move them back.

Is there another way that I have missed?

Comment: What's your goal? Copy or rename?

Comment: I've edited the question: rename.

Comment: *FileUtil.copy* is used for copy not rename. Even if *deleteSource* flag is set, it's still a *copy* operation.

Comment: I know that. My question is whether there is a method that does what I need it to do, i.e. atomic rename/move with a filter on the file names.

Comment: Rename one file/directory is atomic, rename multiple files/directories is not. Instead of *FileSystem.rename(srcFile, dstDir)*, have you tried *FileSystem.rename(srcFile, "dstDir/filename")*? In this way, *dstDir* doesn't have to be empty.

Comment: Well, I currently loop over the files, so that should be OK. That's an idea worth testing... The problem with `FileSystem.rename` though is that I don't know how to go from an instance of `FileStatus` (which I get from `FileSystem.listStatus`) to `java.io.File` *without* first copying the file to my local FS as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9183481/5193203

Comment: So there is no other way?